# Match strings in a particular column to another column even though it occurs in different patterns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

There could be many patterns of a string present in a text. How can we match them?

```
import pandas as pd
import re

lookup = ['100050', '123456', '100045']
lookup_df = pd.DataFrame(lookup, columns = ['Lookup'])

   Lookup
0  100050
1  123456
2  100045
`

text = ['abc 100 050', 'abc 123456','def 100045 ghij','abfgdgh100050','adcb 100 0 50','adc b100050']
text_df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns = ['Text'])


              Text   
0      abc 100 050        
1       abc 123456  
2  def 100045 ghij
3    abfgdgh100050
4    adcb 100 0 50
5    adc b100050

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(re.escape(x)) for x in lookup_df['Lookup'])
text_df['Match'] = text_df['Text'].str.findall(pat).apply(lambda x : x[0] if (len(x)>0) else '' )

Current Output:
Out: 
              Text      Match
0      abc 100 050      
1       abc 123456      123456
2  def 100045 ghij      100045
3    abfgdgh100050       
4    adcb 100 0 50
5    adc b100050
```

If it's noticed, 100050 is present with a space in between in the `Text[0]` and also it is combined as a whole text in `Text[3]` which should not be identified as it is not a whole word. if "abfgdgh100050" is present in the lookup column, then that has to be identified. else, it should not be identified.

```
Expected Output:
Out: 
              Text      Match
0      abc 100 050      100050
1       abc 123456      123456
2  def 100045 ghij      100045
3    abfgdgh100050      NA/BLANK
4    adcb 100 0 50      100050
5    adc b100050        NA/BLANK
```

Comment: how about just replace the whitespace and use findall? `text_df['Text'].str.replace('\s+?','').str.findall("|".join(lookup_df['Lookup'])).str[0]` ? you can adjust the pattern as required and also look at avoiding apply maybe

Comment: @anky, Yeah! That would work too

Answer (score 1):

Works with a couple of modifications to your code:

1. change the pattern to remove the breaks
2. convert the text to ignore all whitespaces for our pattern-matching

```
pat = '|'.join(r"{}".format(re.escape(x)) for x in lookup_df['Lookup'])

text_df['matching_text'] = text_df['Text'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" ", ""))
text_df['Match'] = text_df['matching_text'].str.findall(pat).apply(lambda x : x[0] if (len(x)>0) else '' )
```

Output:

```
              Text  matching_text   Match
0      abc 100 050      abc100050  100050
1       abc 123456      abc123456  123456
2  def 100045 ghij  def100045ghij  100045
3    abfgdgh100050  abfgdgh100050  100050
```

### EDIT

After OP's modification to the question, there is no need to do any fancy regex stuff.

Here is the working code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lookup = {'100050', '123456', '100045'}

print(lookup - (lookup - {'asd', 'sdkj', '100050'}))
lookup_df = pd.DataFrame(lookup, columns=['Lookup'])

text = ['abc 100 050', 'abc 123456','def 100045 ghij','abfgdgh100050 89 289s']
text_df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns = ['Text'])

text_df['Match'] = text_df['Text'].apply(lambda x: list(lookup - (lookup - set(x.split())))).apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) > 0 else np.NaN)

print(text_df)
```

Output:

```
  
                    Text   Match
0            abc 100 050     NaN
1             abc 123456  123456
2        def 100045 ghij  100045
3  abfgdgh100050 89 289s     NaN
```

Comment: What could be done to achieve as per the changed expected output. Any leads will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Serial Lazer, Could you please help on this?

Comment: Actually that makes it even more simple. I've added an EDIT to my answer

Comment: Serial Lazer,  It is same as the output as I got in the first.  Could you please have a look at the expected output and let me know if there could be any change in the code?

Comment: @VV0712 Its impossible to get the same result. Did u try the old solution or the new solution after the `EDIT` section?

Comment: I tried the EDIT section solution and I get the same result as I got in my current solution.   ` Current Output:
Out: 
              Text      Match
0      abc 100 050      
1       abc 123456      123456
2  def 100045 ghij      100045
3    abfgdgh100050       
4    adcb 100 0 50
5    adc b100050 `

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you made multiple recent edits to your question!! I hope you don't expect the answer would magically adapt based on your recent edits?

Comment: I wouldn't expect the answer magically adapting my recent edits.  Thanks a lot for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

What to do if the expected output is changed?

```
Expected Output:
Out: 
              Text      Match
0      abc 100 050      100050
1       abc 123456      123456
2  def 100045 ghij      100045
3    abfgdgh100050      NA/BLANK
4    adcb 100 0 50      100050
5    adc b100050        NA/BLANK
```